# how can run rake resque:scheduler in daemon mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, resque, god

I am using **resque:scheduler gem** in my **rails 3 application**.

How can start `rake resque:scheduler` in `daemon` mode.

and if you know then please let me know,

**How can I configure this task in GOD script?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
PIDFILE=./resque-scheduler.pid BACKGROUND=yes rake resque:scheduler
```

complete doc of resque scheduler available [here](http://rdoc.info/github/bvandenbos/resque-scheduler/master/frames)

Answer (score 6):

I guess you only have to do this

```
BACKGROUND=yes rake resque:scheduler
```

and perhaps that would work check over [here](https://github.com/bvandenbos/resque-scheduler/blob/master/lib/resque_scheduler/tasks.rb#L12)

Hope this help

Comment: thanks Viren have used the way `PIDFILE=./resque-scheduler.pid BACKGROUND=yes rake resque:scheduler` it worked for me

Comment: Note, you should have a resque version >= 1.20 to use BACKGROUND=yes option

Comment: It runs for some time and stops. How can you keep running all the time?

Comment: @aashish create a new SO question and provide a context around it.

Answer (score 0):

try this out

```
rake resque:scheduler BACKGROUND=true
```

or

```
rake resque:scheduler &
```

and now if you want to suppress the output of the rake task try running it with `nohup`

```
nohup rake my:task BACKGROUND=true
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following to configure resque-schedular in God script.

Install god gem

```
gem install god
```

create a file with name as **watch.god** in your project folder.

Add following to **watch.god**

```
God.watch do |w|
  w.name = "resque_schedular"
  w.dir = '/home/machine_name/project_path'
  w.start = "BACKGROUND=yes bundle exec rake environment resque:scheduler"
  w.keepalive
end
```

Run **god** in terminal to test

```
$ god -c path/to/watch.god -D
```

Run **god** in daemon(background) from terminal

```
$ god -c path/to/watch.god
```

Comment: Watch out for the typo in God configuration, it's BACKGROUND not BACKGROUNG